# Most natural way of modelling several many-to-many relationships

Tags: database, database-design

Lets say I have Book and Person. A person can author many books, a book can be authored by many persons. A person has read many books, a book has been read by many persons.

```
Person               Book
------               -----
personId             bookId
```

I could use two relationship tables:

```
has_read             has_authored
--------             ------------
personId, bookId     personId, bookId
```

Or one:

```
person_book_relation
--------------------
personId, bookId, relationType ("read", "authored")
```

Another example could be some kind of subscriber/publisher relationships between Actor and Event.

Are there any guidelines for which to choose?

What if there are more types of relations? Does that change your solution?

A team has many persons with a role. A person can be in many teams. (Just making this up)

```
Team_Person_relation
--------------------
TeamId, PersonId, Role ('Defender', 'Attacker', 'Goalkeeper', 'Midfielder'... etc)
```

If you would use seperate tables this would be 4 tables at least. However, it kind of feels like the team roles are more connected to each other than the "read/authored" relations?

Comment: Another possibility is with 4 tables: `Person, Book, Action, PersonBookAction`

Comment: Good point, the "action" definitively needs to ensure it's integrity somehow

Answer (score 3):

I would use the second type of table unless I encountered a situation where the type of relationship actually affects the columns in the table.

For instance, in the book example, an author might have a date on which they sent it to the publishers, for instance, which invalidates the idea of keeping all the information in one table since that information doesn't apply to readers.

"Goals saved" similarly, would only apply to your goalkeeper.

I suppose the honest, if somewhat trite response is "it depends what information you are trying to extract"- but generally, the more explicitly you can show that "This is the table which describes the relationship between table x and table y" the clearer and easier to maintain your database will be.

Comment: Yeah, if the relations are generic (no extra data from extra columns) it might be best to use just one table? Especially if you often want all the relations at the same time. Like in the team example I guess you often want to retrieve the whole team. When there's just two relations like the author/read. It might be nice to separate them I think for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

It mostly depends on you, as a database creator, as both solutions are correct. What should be taken into consideration is mostly how the data is going to be used in the future (or at least how is it predicted now to be going to be used). Some examples:

1. If you force too many many-to-many relations in one table you need to always remember that "there are other relations there" when working with one of them. For example if you wish to see all people that did not author any book you need to construct the left-join query in a way it filters "read" relationship. As your queries get more complex and include more tables and more outer joins it is easy to get unrequired results.
2. An example with team roles suggests that the list of roles may change in the future. It is therefore better solution to keep this role in relationship's column. Moreover, the relationship designates here "being the member of a team" and role of this membership is only this membership's property.
3. If you wish to store some additional information with your many-to-many relationship (such as date of authoring, or how much did reader like the book) it will suggest separate tables as otherwise many sparse columns would be used to handle all possible relationships.
4. And last but no least: performance. Sometimes it may be hard to design and use indexes effectively if tables try to contain too much "unrelated" data.

Comment: In the team example I guess you often want to retrieve all roles at the same time which would be easier if they all were contained in the same table.

Comment: The more I think of it it is a matter of whether we model "being in relationship" (separare table) or "being property of some relationship" (common table). In people-book example a common table would mean "there is SOME relationship between book and person" which is nonsense.

Comment: Could you give an example of both so I can understand the difference that you are referring to? Between "relationship" and "property of some relationship"